# Assign boost shared memory to structure

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I am using boost lib to reserve shared memory. I have been able to reserve for vector of float,int,string type but not sure how to allocate for structure type?

I used the following code to reserve memory for vector of int type(I am only writing some codes):

```
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator_int;
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator_int> vector_int;
.............
 const ShmemAllocator_int alloc_inst_int (segment.get_segment_manager());

 vector_int *IMG_ID_LIST = segment.construct<vector_int>("IMG_ID_LIST")(alloc_inst_int);
```

How can I use the above code in case of allocating memory to structure?

I want to reserve memory for a structure in which I can store the above vector with similar ones. Eg my structure will be somewhat like below:

```
struct img{
vector<int> Id;
vector<float> size;
vector <int> Name;
}
```

How can I reserve memory for this structure? And my another confusion is after I allocate a memory to the structure img should I also allocate memory for the Id,size and Name too which are the structure elements?

I have to get the information of thousands of img in the memory so if there is any other effective way. Please mention.